# Is there a way to prevent having to await an async method returning a stream?

Tags: asynchronous, stream, async-await, dart

We currently have a method that returns a `Future<Stream<Position>>` just because internally we have to await the result of a method returning a `Future` before we can call another method that returns the `Stream<Position>` which we are actually interested in. Here is the code:

```
Future<Stream<Position>> getPositionStream(
    [LocationOptions locationOptions = const LocationOptions()]) async {
  PermissionStatus permission = await _getLocationPermission();

  if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    if (_onPositionChanged == null) {
      _onPositionChanged = _eventChannel
          .receiveBroadcastStream(
              Codec.encodeLocationOptions(locationOptions))
          .map<Position>(
              (element) => Position._fromMap(element.cast<String, double>()));
    }

    return _onPositionChanged;
  } else {
    _handleInvalidPermissions(permission);
  }

  return null;
}
```

So what happens here is:

1. We await the `_getLocationPermission()` method so that we can test if the user grants us permission to access to the location services on their device (Android or iOS);
2. If the user grants us permission we return a `Stream<Position>` which will update every time the device registers a location change.

I have the feeling we can also handle this without doing an await and returning a `Future`. Something along the lines of:

1. Manually create and return an instance of the `Stream<Position>` class;
2. Handle the logic of checking the permissions and calling the `_eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream` in the `then()` method of the `Future<PermissionStatus>` returned from the `_getLocationPermission()` method (so we don't have to await it);
3. Copy the events send on the stream from the `_eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream` onto the earlier created (and returned) stream.

Somehow this seems to be possible, but also includes some overhead in managing the stream and make sure it closes and is cleaned up correctly during the live cycle of the plugin or when the user unsubscribes pass through the events to the `_eventChannel` etc.

So I guess the question would be, what would be the best way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write the code as an `async*` function, which will return a `Stream` and still allows `await` in the body:

```
Stream<Position> getPositionStream(
    [LocationOptions locationOptions = const LocationOptions()]) async* {
  PermissionStatus permission = await _getLocationPermission();

  if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    if (_onPositionChanged == null) {
      _onPositionChanged = _eventChannel
          .receiveBroadcastStream(
              Codec.encodeLocationOptions(locationOptions))
          .map<Position>(
              (element) => Position._fromMap(element.cast<String, double>()));
    }

    yield* _onPositionChanged;
  } else {
    _handleInvalidPermissions(permission);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using a non-`async` function, you can also use [`StreamCompleter`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/async/2.0.5/async/StreamCompleter-class.html) from `package:async`.
It allows you to return a `Stream` now, even if you only get the real stream later. When that happens, you "complete" the `StreamCompleter` with the real stream, and the original stream will behave as if it was the real stream.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation, exactly what I needed!